# How to execute UPDATE query in bulk

Tags: database, sqlite

I need to update values in my DB table. Below are the queries I have written for the same.

```
 update product set product_name='AAAA' where product_id='1'
 update product set product_name='BBB' where product_id='2'
 update product set product_name='CCC' where product_id='3'
 update product set product_name='DDDD' where product_id='4'
```

When I update these above statements, only my 4th row is getting updated. 
I searched for executing UPDATE commands in a bulk, but didn't find any help yet.

Please let me know how to make sure all the above commands get executed without overwrite with last statement.

I am using Sqlite , not mySql.

Comment: Please show the code where you're trying to execute these statements.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
update product set product_name='BBB' where product_id IN ('1' , '2', '3', '4' );
```

Just be careful that IN operator usually does not support more than 1000 parameters.

EDIT:

Now that you have changed your question. Have you tried putting a semicolon in the end of each statement?

Comment: Thanks for help , Please let me know how to execute above If I have update multiple "product_name" values.  Edited my question.

Comment: Tried putting semicolon at end of each statement , but that is not working in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN`

```
 update product set product_name='BBB' where product_id IN ('1','2','3','4')
```